# in agenda vs on agenda

Tags: prepositions

I would like to inquire about the correct usage of prepositions in/on in the following sentences:

```
I plan to finish this work quickly because I have additional tasks in my agenda
I plan to finish this work quickly because I have additional tasks on my agenda
I plan to finish this work quickly because I have additional tasks scheduled on my agenda.
```

please which sentence is more accurate in terms of prepositions usage?

Comment: Which do you think is the most idiomatic construction?

Comment: Generally use *on my agenda*, considering an agenda strictly speaking is written down.